# Natbib + Chapterbib

Tags: natbib

I want to put a separate bibliography at the end of each chapter, called "References", and a global bibliography at the end of my report, called "Bibliography". I'm using Natbib and tried Chapterbib. But it doesn't seem that Chapterbib can create a global bibliography at the end. Is there any other package that I can use to achieve this formatting? 
I know the duplicate option of Chapterbib. But it is still separated by chapters at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> But it doesn't seem that Chapterbib can create a global bibliography at the end.

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: You can have both a global bibliography as well as per-chapter bibliographies. Here's an excerpt from pp 3f. of the user guide of the `chapterbib` package:

> **7 Overall bibliography**: To have a cohesive bibliography
>   for the whole document, plus individual bibs in the chapters, put
>   `\bibliography commands` in the included chapters plus in the root
>   file. Make sure the `\bibliographystyle` for the overall bibliography
>   appears *first*, before any chapters are included. Run LATEX; run
>   BibTEX on the root file; run BibTEX on each included file; run LATEX;
>   run LATEX. This produces an independent 'overall' bibliography which
>   only makes sense for various 'named' bibliography styles; a numbered
>   style, or one with any type of automatic enumeration (like Me2007a,
>   Me2007b) will give unrelated numbers in each bibliography and lead
>   to confusion.
>
> BibTEX will complain about multiple `\bibdata` commands when it
>   makes the whole bibliography, but it should obey the first. If you don't
>   want to see any error messages from bibtex, or if you don't want to put
>   the main `\bibliographystyle` command first in the document, then
>   use `\usepackage[rootbib]{chapterbib}` when you run LATEX first;
>   run BibTEX on the root file; change to `\usepackage{chapterbib}`;
>   run LATEX; run BibTEX on each included file; run LATEX; run LATEX.